# Filter an WordPress Function in (general-template.php)

Tags: functions, filters, core

Sorry if it's a duplicate question, 
I just want to change a little the WordPress core function `get_header()` with new function `new_get_header()`.

```
function new_get_header() {
    // new header fragments;
}
```

**Is this possible?**

```
add_filter( 'get_header', 'new_get_header' );
```

**Or should I use:**

```
add_action( 'init', 'new_get_header' );
```

And call it as a function instead of original.

```
new_get_header();
// Content
// Footer
```

Comment: why not put your header file in a child theme instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, no, neither of your two alternatives is "possible" in the sense of able or at all likely to do what you seem to want it to do.

There is no get_header **filter** - so the first alternative won't do anything.

The second one might do **something**, depending on what your function contained, but isn't how this is done.

There **is** a get_header **action hook** whose use is described in the Codex here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/get_header
 It does allow you to narrow its scope by name of specific header file. Depending on what exactly you want to happen when it fires, it might be one way to achieve whatever it is you want to achieve.

Since there are no specific get_header filters, the main ways to modify your header are either to create one or more new header.php or header-{name}.php template files for your child-theme (you can have multiple ones for templates to choose from).

If you want to change specific elements in your theme's header without hacking it or creating a new header(-name).php file, you can use one of the filters you can find in wp-includes/theme.php. https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5.3/src/wp-includes/theme.php#L0

Determining which alternative or alternatives you need will depend on what "fragments" you need to modify.

Comment: After several tests. I don't see any effective way of doing `add_filter()`. The only change i wanted to make like this: `$mypath . 'header-{name}.php'`. I copied the original function and added the path to my new function and it's **working**. I also learned the reason why Action Hook was on `get_header()`, thanks for detailed answer!

Answer (score 1):

**In my opinion**, I don't think it is a nice idea to modify WordPress core functions. If there is something you need to add or remove from the function(s), doing a

```
add_filter( 'core_function_name', 'your_custom_function' );
```

or

```
add_action( 'core_function_name', 'your_custom_function' );
```

will give you the result you need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yeah i know that changing WP core it's not a good idea. But I just wanted to change paths for templates of `get_header( $template );` and link it to my new header template path which is not on main theme directory. This change will have 0 effect on WordPress but will improve my theme structure... I will give a try if `add_filter` works.

Comment: Okay. If it works, please don't forget to accept the answer. :)